# Nginx static site fetching resources from root instead of subdirectory

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'm trying to serve both an API and frontend static site from the same EC2 instance. I'm using nginx and my server block as follows with the API being in port 8001 and static files to be served to `/sub/`:

```
    server_name  abc.def.com www.abc.def.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
}

location /sub/ {
    alias /var/www/subweb/;
    index index.html;
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="/vendor.aea0bbda027e3c98f5c1.js"></script>
```

However what happens is my **index.html** tries to fetch the resources (javascript file) from root instead of **/sub/**.

How can I fix that so that it points to the right location?

*UPDATE - as advised, I have switched the order of locations but it's still not working as intended:

```
server_name  abc.def.com www.abc.def.com;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location /sub/ {
    alias /var/www/subweb/;
    index index.html;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
}
```

Comment: Fix the broken URL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that's ideal as it will mean changing every single link on the site.

Comment: So if your URLs are _not_ in `/sub/` then why do you expect that `location` to apply to them?

Comment: they are relative links, just like the script. I would assume the behaviour would be the same as above.

Comment: I should add that It's a React site. Maybe that's what's causing the confusion

Comment: The example you posted isn't relative!

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of locations.

Comment: Oh, this surely does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated as per your advice but the outcome is the same.